# openni_node.launch: Warning: recursive print statement has occurred

Tags: ros, kinect, openni-node, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure if this is a problem or not.  On the latest version of the ni stack running on the latest Diamondback and Ubuntu 10.04, I get the following warnings when launching openni_node.launch:

```
$ roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch
core service [/rosout] found
process[openni_node1-1]: started with pid [32041]
process[kinect_base_link-2]: started with pid [32042]
process[kinect_base_link1-3]: started with pid [32043]
process[kinect_base_link2-4]: started with pid [32045]
process[kinect_base_link3-5]: started with pid [32056]
[/openni_node1] Number devices connected: 1
Warning: recursive print statement has occurred.  Throwing out recursive print.
Warning: recursive print statement has occurred.  Throwing out recursive print.
Warning: recursive print statement has occurred.  Throwing out recursive print.
Warning: recursive print statement has occurred.  Throwing out recursive print.
Warning: recursive print statement has occurred.  Throwing out recursive print.
```

The warning always repeats 5 times as above.  The Kinect and the node seem to be working fine, just thought I would report it.

--patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9301/openni_node.launch:-warning:-recursive-print-statement-has-occurred/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2011-03-05

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on 2011-03-10**:
I've got this too. 10.10 on a VirtualBox machine running ontop of ATI video card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for the report.  This sort of thing can go directly into a ticket like this one.  https://kforge.ros.org/openni/Trac/ticket/1

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-03-05**:
Please mark answers as "accepted" or "favorite" by clicking the checkbox so they show as answered.

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2011-03-05**:
Thanks Tully.  Will open a ticket for such things in the future.